# TIME Magazine RSS Feed

Tags: android, kotlin, http, postman, rss

I'm trying to load the TIME magazine RSS feed through an http request: https://rss.time.com/web/time/rss/top/index.xml

Which comes from their ancient page [here](https://content.time.com/time/business/article/0,8599,1111467,00.html).

Even just through postman, I can't get the feed to come back properly. I am getting their main html website page instead. I've tried using a large number of `Accept` headers including `application/rss+xml` and `application/xml`. Am I missing something or do they just not support RSS anymore?

Comment: That page was updated in 2006.  None of the links are working.  Try the following instead.  https://time.com/feed/